# User-defined record as an OUT parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

This is my current code.  My error is that COUNTRY_REC must be declared.  I understand all of that I just can't find *anything* online that talks about records as out parameters.  This is a requirement of the problem.  I have to be very close to the solution but I just don't understand.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE find_region_and_currency_sp(
    p_country_name IN COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE,
    p_country_rec OUT country_rec)
    IS
      TYPE country_rec IS RECORD(
        country_name COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE,
        region COUNTRIES.REGION_ID%TYPE,
        currency COUNTRIES.CURRENCY_CODE%TYPE);
    country_record country_rec;
    BEGIN 
      SELECT COUNTRY_NAME, REGION_ID, CURRENCY_CODE INTO country_rec
      FROM COUNTRIES
      where COUNTRY_NAME = p_country_name;
    END;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: The signature of the return data type has to be available to the calling program. Since you currently declare `COUNTRY_REC` inside of the proc, it can only be used within the proc. If you need to use a RECORD as the return, simply define it in a package and reference it as `PACKAGE_NAME.COUNTRY_REC` in the proc and the calling code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your record `TYPE` `COUNTRY_REC` is defined inside procedure which is not accessible within scope of procedure parameters.

You have the following options.

Create and store a `TYPE OBJECT COUNTRY_REC` with same structure as that of the query result and compatible datatypes.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE country_rec AS OBJECT (
    country_name   VARCHAR2(10),
    region         VARCHAR2(10),
    currency       VARCHAR2(5)
);
```

You then don't need another local record variable.But, you need to initialize using `NEW` keyword as shown. You can then simply fetch the values into corresponding record elements.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE find_region_and_currency_sp (
    p_country_name   IN countries.country_name%TYPE,
    p_country_rec    OUT country_rec
)
    IS
BEGIN
 p_country_rec := NEW country_rec(NULL,NULL,NULL);  --Initialization
    SELECT
        country_name,
        region_id,
        currency_code
    INTO
        p_country_rec.country_name,p_country_rec.region,p_country_rec.currency
    FROM
        countries
    WHERE
        country_name = p_country_name;

END;
```

The other Option is to define the record in the package scope in the package specification.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_country_op 
AS

 TYPE country_rec IS RECORD(
        country_name COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE,
        region COUNTRIES.REGION_ID%TYPE,
        currency COUNTRIES.CURRENCY_CODE%TYPE);

PROCEDURE find_region_and_currency_sp (
    p_country_name   IN COUNTRIES.country_name%TYPE,
    p_country_rec    OUT country_rec
);

END;
/
```

And then include the same procedure inside the `PACKAGE BODY`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_country_op..
..
..
    PROCEDURE find_region_and_currency_sp (
        p_country_name   IN countries.country_name%TYPE,
        p_country_rec    OUT country_rec
    )
    IS
```

..

**Calling the procedure**. You can call the procedure as follows.

*Case 1:*

```
 DECLARE
    v_country_rec country_rec;  --Global Scope

    BEGIN
    find_region_and_currency_sp('India',v_country_rec);
    END;
    /
```

*Case 2:*

```
DECLARE
v_country_rec pkg_country_op.country_rec; --Package Global variable

BEGIN
pkg_country_op.find_region_and_currency_sp('India',v_country_rec);
END;
/
```